# Input String Was Not Found In A Correct Format Error While Uploading Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, syntax-error

I was trying to get an upload feature in my website built using ASP.NET. But it keeps throwing me this error
Server Error in '/' Application.

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 43:lblDescription.Text = "Problem Description:";
Line 44:txtDescription.Text = dr["problem_desc"].ToString();
Line 45:this.lblFileName.Text = dal.GetFileName(ConstClass.ConnOLEDB, Convert.ToInt16(dr["problem"].ToString()));
Line 46:break;
Line 47:case "2": //Alter
```

**Source File:** C:\eteam\eteam.net - on\eteamuno\module_edit.aspx.cs    Line: 45

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12639413
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +224
   System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +41
   eteamuno.module_edit.editvalue() in C:\eteam\eteam.net - on\eteamuno\module_edit.aspx.cs:45
   eteamuno.module_edit.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\eteam\eteam.net - on\eteamuno\module_edit.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Clearly `dr["problem"]` does not contain a numeric value when this exception occurs.  What does it contain?  And how do you want your system to respond when it encounters a record which doesn't contain a valid numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

while converting your numeric String into numeric , instead of calling Int16 call Int32 as Int16 is a short.

> Convert.ToInt32() -> Converts string numeric into Integer.

**Replace This :**

```
this.lblFileName.Text = dal.GetFileName(ConstClass.ConnOLEDB, Convert.ToInt16(dr["problem"].ToString()));
```

**With Following :**

```
this.lblFileName.Text = dal.GetFileName(ConstClass.ConnOLEDB, Convert.ToInt32(dr["problem"].ToString()));
```